# How do I export data to a CSV file in C# making sure that Excel can work with it?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export-to-csv

We are exporting a list of dealer information to CSV so the client can work with it in Excel, and import it back into the app.

When we edit the CSV file itself it works perfect, but when Excel opens and saves the file, it loses all CSV structure.

Quotes are removed, and semicolons are removed as well.

Our export code looks like this now:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=export_dealers_{0}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.csv; charset=utf-8", countryCode, DateTime.Now));
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
Response.Write(ToCsv(list));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The `toCSV` function just returns a string with all fields each within quotes, separated with a semicolon.

We had it different before, but had to add extra encoding data, so it doesn't garble up the special characters, like `ç` or `ñ` ...

The above piece of code exports a CSV file that seems correct, but when Excel opens it, and saves it (even without changing a field) all semicolons and quotes are removed, and if you try the `Save as` functionality it detects to save it as a `.txt` file instead of CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
var lines = new string[10][];

var csv = string.Join("\r\n", lines.Select(words =>
              string.Join(",", words.Select(word =>
                  "\"" + word.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")))));

File.WriteAllText("file.csv", csv);
```

Excel reads it in it's simplest form.

Comment: i'm going to try this out but it seems like far to simplistic :), how about special characters like ñ or ç do these work? because french and spanish and other languages are filled with these irragular characters :) and that is why we had to do all the encoding stuff.

Comment: Eventually, you're saving it just like a text file, seperated by commas and so. If a text file would support the characters, so will the csv, and so will excel.

Comment: main difference is we don't save to a file, but output it to the user directly in a stream of data. for that we need to set the headers and encoding to utf8. 
you save it as a file, of course we can try that too... i'll see what it does later this afternoon

Comment: we ended up saving it as a file, and sending the file to the user, somehow that was easier and fixed the issue, however i'm sure sending it directly should be possible somehow. However your solution did fix the issue.